# How to print numbers at the end of the line?

Tags: python

I have a file I am reading from.
I need to output a copy of the file where line numbers are simply appended to the end of each line.
I tried the following code but couldn't get it to work:

```python
with open('s.txt', 'r') as f, open("1.txt", "w") as out:
    abc_list = [[float(n) for n in line.split()] for line in f]
    for i,line in enumerate(abc_list):
        out.write('{i+0:2}\n'.format(line.rstrip('\n')))
```

The input-file contains data similar to the following:

```
1    2     
5    6   
25   85
```

The shows what the contents of the output file should be:

```
 1 2 1 
 5 6 2
 25 85 3
```

I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Comment: `line` is a list of floats created by the list comprehension, it's not a line from the file. You don't need to use `rstrip()` when writing to the file.

Comment: how can I print the number at the end line?

Comment: `rstrip()` can only be used on strings. For example, `"spam".rstrip()` is a valid line of code in python. You seem to be trying to invoke the `rstrip()` method of a list. Lists do not have an `rstrip()` method. You would get the same error if you wrote `[1, 2, 3].rstrip()`

Comment: That error has nothing to do with printing the number at the end of the line. It's just because you're calling `rstrip()` when you don't need to.

Comment: Why are you converting the input-file data into floating-point number? Why are you parsing the input-file? If you want to append a line number at the end of each line, you can simply leave the original data in string form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got  `KeyError: 'i'` with the answer of Barmar .. i fixed it now. Thanks for the help

```
  with open('s.txt', 'r') as f, open("1.txt", "w") as out:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            nums = [float(n) for n in line.split()]
            for n in nums:
                out.write(str(n) + ' ')
            out.write(f'{i+0:2}\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `line.rstrip()`. At that point `line` is a list of numbers, not a line from the input file. You should loop over the numbers and write each of them without a newline.

Then write `i` to the file at the end of the line.

If you want the line numbers to start at 1, use that as an argument to `enumerate()`.

```
with open('s.txt', 'r') as f, open("1.txt", "w") as out:
    abc_list = [[float(n) for n in line.split()] for line in f]
    for i,nums in enumerate(abc_list, 1):
        for n in nums:
            out.write(str(n) + ' ')
        out.write('{i:2}\n'.format(i))
```

You can also avoid creating the list of all lines.

```
with open('s.txt', 'r') as f, open("1.txt", "w") as out:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        nums = [float(n) for n in line.split()]
        for n in nums:
            out.write(str(n) + ' ')
        out.write('{i:2}\n'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will append line numbers to the end of every line of a file:

```python
def get_suffixed_iterator(rf, sep =" "):
    sep = str(sep)
    rf = iter(rf)
    rf = map(str, rf)
    rf = map(str.strip, rf)
    for num, text in enumerate(rf, 1):
        yield text + sep + str(num)
```

Below, we test the function:

```python
f = ["orange\n\n", "eggs", "\n\napple\n\n\n"]
for lin in get_suffixed_iterator(f):
    print(lin)
```

```python
with open('readme.txt', 'r') as rf, open("writeme.txt", "w") as wf:
    it = append_line_numbers(rf)
    for line in it:
        print(line, file=wf, end="\n")
```